# Jupyter: downloading notebook as PDF via LaTeX

Tags: miktex, python, miktex2.9

I am using [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org) for the first time.  I am trying to download a notebook "as PDF via LaTeX".  However, messages pop up indicating that the required files

`tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def` (part of the xetex-def package)

and

`tex\xelatex\xetexurl\url.sty` (part of the xetexurl package)

are missing.  The problem is that neither package seems to be available at

http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/ctan.org/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/.

Using the MiKTeX Package Manager (which I have synchronized), I have installed the graphics-def package, which apparently includes the xetex.def file.  But the downloading process is still not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From your description it is not possible to decide if the problem is in miktex or in jupyter or in something local to your PC. I never heard of an url.sty in such a location and this sound like wrong code. Also I just installed a package and it worked fine .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Trying this on a mac, downloading as "LaTeX" and then running through `pdflatex` worked fine.  The download as "pdf via LaTeX" also gave me (different) error messages (this time about directories not existing).

Answer (score 3):

I know it is not exactly what you want but have you tried to print it to pdf using your browser (ctrl+p)? It is simple and the "you print what you see" approach is great to share a reports/analysis with people that do not code or use the jupyter enviroment. Not publication ready by any means but gets the job done. Just make sure your plots and figures are not on interactive mode otherwise they will not be displayed.

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer) to hide your code from the pdf or explore these [extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) to improve your jupyter documents. If you really want to make your publications from inside jupyter, this [tutorial](http://blog.juliusschulz.de/blog/ultimate-ipython-notebook) attempts that and has some great tips.

I always had trouble with exporting my jupyter nb to pdf through latex. Quick search and you see that A LOT of people do. I could get some stuff worked out but the formatting was lackluster with code and plots not displayed the way I wanted. I eventually accepted that the jupyter notebook could not produce "publish-ready" pdfs easily. When I want that, I generate plots/figures/code on jupyter and call them on a latex file.

Comment: so how do you save it to pdf after ctrl + p?

Comment: I think all major browsers have that option. For chrome follow this:
https://www.wikihow.com/Save-a-Web-Page-as-a-PDF-in-Google-Chrome

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04 with Jupyter installed via `pip`, I had to do the following to install all fonts and generic packages for Latex:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
sudo apt-get install cm-super
sudo apt-get install texlive-generic-recommended
wget https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/2.1.2/pandoc-2.1.2-1-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i pandoc-2.1.2-1-amd64.deb
```

Hope this helps!